# Crear una función booleana que devuelva si una cadena de caracteres termina en una letra

Tags: c, string

Tengo problemas con este codigo en lenguaje C. No me compila.

Acá te paso la línea donde me tira el error y el mensaje del error

En el programa principal main() me da el error:

```
if(leer_letraZ(vec[i].(cade[],letra) == true) 

Message: request for member of non-aggregate type before '.' token
```

Aclaración: es en la función -----> `leer_letraZ(vec[i].(cade[],letra) == true)`

Entiendo que dentro de la función, se puede leer un vector y con un ciclo for recorrerlo, pero estoy intentando ver de que manera me lea los nombres de las personas que tienen la ultima letra terminada en "z" y me los cuente. Eso es todo lo que debe hacer el programa. Mostrar los nombres de los alumnos que termina con la letra z y me los cuente nada más !!!

---

enunciado:

a) Leer los datos de 5 alumnos (nombre, edad, nota). Usar struct y vector.

b) Mostrar los datos de los 5 alumnos y finalmente cuantos de ellos tienen su
nombre terminado en la letra z.

c) Diseñar una función booleana que devuelva si una cadena de caracteres
termina en una letra que también se pasar como parametro.

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

//--------------------------

struct alumno
{
  char nombre[30];
  int edad;
  int nota;     
       
};

// procedimiento para leer los datos

void leer_alumno(struct alumno &a)
{ 
   printf("__________________________________ \n");
   printf("\n");
   printf("\n Ingrese nombre: "); 
   gets(a.nombre); 
   fflush(stdin); 
   
   printf("\n Ingrese edad: "); 
   scanf("%d",&a.edad); 
   fflush(stdin); 
   
   printf("\n Ingrese nota: "); 
   scanf("%d",&a.nota); 
   fflush(stdin); 
};

// procedimiento para visualizar el grupo de datos.

void mostrar_alumno(struct alumno a) 
{ 
   printf("\n");
   printf("__________________________________ \n");
   printf("\n");
   printf("\n\n\n Datos del Alumno: "); 
   printf("\n Nombre: %s", a.nombre); 
   printf("\n Edad : %d", a.edad); 
   printf("\n Nota: %d", a.nota); 
   printf("\n");

};

//aca se observa el vector de tipo struct que se va a leer

void leer_nota(struct alumno nota[]) 
{
     
  int i; 
  
  for(i=1;i<=2;i++) 
  {
    leer_alumno(nota[i]); 
  } 

};

void mostrar_nota(struct alumno nota[]) 
{
   int i; 
   
   for(i=1;i<=2;i++) 
   {
     mostrar_alumno(nota[i]); 
   } 
};

/*función booleana que devuelva si una cadena de caracteres termina en una 
  letra que también se pasara como parametro. */

bool leer_letraZ(char cad[10], char z)
{
 //cade me da lo que hay dento de esa ulitima posicion. (indico la ultima 
   posición del vector -1) 
   if(cad[strlen(cad)-1]== z)
       return true;
   else
       return false;
       
}
//procedimiento que muestra la cantidad 
void mostrar_nro(char cad[30] ,int p) 
{ 
  printf("\n %s %d ",cad, p); 

}

void pausar()
{
   printf("\n");
   system("pause");  
     
}
//--------------------------------

int main()
{
    struct alumno a;
    struct alumno nota[2];
    int i;
    int cont =0;
        
    leer_nota(nota);
    mostrar_nota(nota);
    
    char cade[10];
    char letra;
    int vec[2];
    
   
   //mostrar_nro("\n La cantidad son: ",leer_letraZ( ));
   
   for(i=1;i<2;i++)
   {
          
     if(leer_letraZ(cade[],letra) == true)
     {
       printf("%s termina con la letra %c\n",cade,letra);
        cont++; 
     }
     else
     {
       printf("%s no termina con la letra %c\n",cade,letra);       
     }
         
   }
     
   pausar();
   return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Intenta usa expresiones regulares para determinar si la cadena termina en una letra.

Comment: Uffff..  eso es matar pulguitas muy muy chiquititas a cañonazos **de los muy muy gordos** :-D

Comment: Pues vaya... resulta que a pesar de todo el código que has metido en la pregunta, la línea en la que dices que te sale un error no aparece. Aparentemente has puesto un código de otra versión distinta a la que te da el error.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes una función booleana que devuelve si una cadena de caracteres termina en una letra.

```
bool acaba_en(char *cadena, char letra)
{
    int longitud = strlen(cadena);
    return cadena[longitud - 1] == letra;
}
```

Que es más o menos lo que ya tenías. Así que tu error no tiene nada que ver con ello, el error es claro y conciso, tal vez no lo entiendes por estar en inglés. Te lo traduzco:

> ```
> Message: request for member of non-aggregate type before '.' token
> ```

> ```
> Mensage: se pide un miembro de un tipo no-agregado antes del símbolo '.'
> ```

Te está diciendo que el punto (`.`) hay que usarlo para leer miembros de objetos, y tú lo usas para algo muy extraño que no tiene ni pies ni cabeza:

```
vec[i].(cade[],letra)
//    ^ <---- ???????????????
```

Por lo que veo, ese código ni siquiera lo estás compilando, así que todo arreglado.